# Wordpress. Как правильно вывести посты с переводом с помощью плагина WPGlobus

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, wordpress-multisite, мультиязычность

Вывожу кастомные типы записей(и обычные записи, присвоены какой-то рубрике) в свой шаблон ... Но поставил этот плагин, и он выводит вот таким текстом -

```
{:ru}русский текст{:}{:en}english text{:}
```

Подскажите, кто сталкивался с таким? Как решить? Чтобы когда русский язык - выводило русским, а английский - английским

Comment: Не надо пользоваться этим убожеством.  Есть бесплатный Polylang.

Comment: Почитать документацию к плагину. Но если нет специальных требований, то лучше воспользоваться советом **KAGGDesign**-а

Comment: Там в документации - ничего про это не сказано, уже просмотрел